# Cauchy's functional equation $f (x+y)=f (x)+f(y)$ in subdomains

Tags: functional-equations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is additive ($f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$) and monotonic on a set $D\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $|D|>1$, $0\in D$ and $-a\in D$ whenever $a\in D$. Assume nothing about the behavior of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus D$.

Is it true that, for all $x\in D$, $f(x)=\alpha x$ for some $\alpha\neq 0$?

Comment: You should include the functional equation, both in title and body. Most will know it, but it may improve searchability. If $D$ isn't closed under addition, the answer is trivially negative (but the question doesn't make a lot of sense, either, then, sorry).

Comment: thank you. and what if $D$ is closed under addition but is still finite?

Comment: @user_xyz Finite and closed under addition?  That's practically a synonym for "a subset of $\{0\}$"... which clearly contradicts your assumption that $|D|>1$.

Comment: @ErickWong: Is it the case then that if $D$ is closed under addition and satisies the above conditions, then $D=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @user_xyz Are you asking whether $D=\mathbb R$ is the only additively closed domain for which the original question holds for all $f$?  Certainly not: even without the monotonicity constraint, the claim is true for $D =\mathbb Q$ and $D =\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No!" considering axiom of choice which is sufficient to prove that there is a [Hamel basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html).

Let $ H $ be a Hamel basis containing, say $ 1 $ and $ \sqrt 2 $. Define $ f $ such that $ f ( 1 ) = 1 $, $ f \left( \sqrt 2 \right) = 2 $ and $ f ( a ) = 0 $ for each $ a \in H \setminus \left\{ 1 , \sqrt 2 \right\} $. Then taking $ D = \left\{ - \sqrt 2 , -1 , 0 , 1 , \sqrt 2 \right\} $, $ f $ is increasing on $ D $ but there is no $ \alpha \in \mathbb R $ such that $ f ( x ) = \alpha x $ for all $ x \in D $.